# how fix login oracle problem 'invalid username/password; logon denied' in oracle 18c

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle18c

I installed Oracle18c XE and with `SYS` user I run these statements:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE; 
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB1;
```

Then iI create TableSpace

```
CREATE TABLESPACE A251_TABLESPACE DATAFILE 'a251_data.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M  MAXSIZE 1G;  
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE A251_TEMP_TABLESPACE TEMPFILE 'a251_data_temp.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M  MAXSIZE 1G;
```

And I created user `ashmeta`  .

```
CREATE USER ashmeta IDENTIFIED BY ashmeta 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE A251_TABLESPACE 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE A251_TEMP_TABLESPACE;
```

and I grant DBA to `ashmeta`.
So why when I want connect to this user do I see this error?

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
> Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

Comment: how are you connecting?

Comment: @Kaus2b connect ashmeta/ashmeta

Comment: connect ashmeta/ashmeta@PDB --> where pdb is the name of the plugable database, in your case xepdb1

Comment: @RobertoHernandez TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: @RobertoHernandez how fix this problem?

Comment: what is the server name and the port used in the listener ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Service name : CLRExtProc And port 1521

Comment: I asked for the server name, not the service name. connect to the CDB as sysdba and run this select : `select host_name, instance_name from v$instance;`

Comment: @RobertoHernandez hostname:DESKTOP-74TG78P and instance_name = xe

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a local user in a PDB, so you can only connect to it via listener.
This can be achieved either by putting an entry into tnsnames.ora or by EZconnect. The latter does not need further configuration:

```
connect ashmeta/ashmeta@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

This works as long the database runs locally and the service name of the PDB is XEPDB1. If the database instance runs on a different host, use that hostname instead of localhost. The service name of the PDB you can find out by asking when connected to the PDB by issuing

```
show parameter service_names
```